# DevForce Classic query timeout

Tags: c#, wcf, devforce

We are having issues with our DevForce Classic application timing out on queries. We keep getting the error "the request was aborted". The closest match to the problem we are having if described on the DevForce EF version [here](http://drc.ideablade.com/xwiki/bin/view/Documentation/understand-timeouts). It says that the error "the transaction was aborted" indicated that the timeout on the TransactionSettings is too short. The problem I am seeing is that the timeout (and the DefaultQueryStrategy's TransactionSettings) are read-only.

Can anyone provide some guidance on how to resolve this issue?

Comment: What does this have to do with WCF?

Comment: If he's using WCF the timeout may be caused by the request operation timing out.  The error message doesn't help much - it could be WCF, the transaction, or the DB query timing out.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a custom DefaultQueryStrategy on the PersistenceManager.  For example the following will use the usual defaults and custom TransactionSettings with a 2 minute timeout:

```
var settings = new TransactionSettings(   
               UseDTCOption.UseConfigurationSetting, 
               System.Transactions.IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted, 
               new TimeSpan(0, 2, 0));
var queryStrategy = new QueryStrategy(QueryStrategy.Normal, settings);
myPM.DefaultQueryStrategy = queryStrategy;
```

If you don't want to change the DefaultQueryStrategy for the entire PM, you can pass a query strategy on the RdbQuery.  For example:

```
var query = new RdbQuery(typeof(Customer));
query.QueryStrategy = new QueryStrategy(myPM.DefaultQueryStrategy, settings);
```

It is possible that the timeout is coming from WCF or the database.  If changing the transaction timeout value doesn't help, post the <binding> element from your BOS .config file.